# Visual Studio 2015 c# Timer problems

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Hey just wondering if anyone could help me out with a problem I'm encountering with a timer in my windows form application. Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void game_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int count = 0;
            count++;
            timeLabel.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(count).ToString();
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that whenever the window that this applies to opens and then after that nothing happens and I'm unable to do anything. When removing this code the window works fine so I'm unsure why its not working in relation to this section of code. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: `game_Timer_Tick` should automatically fire at every timer interval, you shouldn't make your own loop inside that. remove `while true`

Comment: Your application doesn't have time to actually show the updates to the label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display number of seconds since timer start, then declare field for holding start time:

```
private DateTime startTime;
```

Assign this field when you are starting timer:

```
game_Timer.Interval = 1000; // fire event each second
startTime = DateTime.Now;
game_Timer.Start();
```

And use it in Tick handler:

```
private void game_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeLabel.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString();
}
```

---

What is wrong with your code? You have infinite loop inside Tick event handler. So when event fires first time, you are entering this loop and never exit it. And you are unable to do anything, because your application is busy with constant updating time label.

You can also use counter instead of saving timer start time. But you will need field anyway:

```
private int count = 0;
```

And event handler:

```
private void game_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeLabel.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(++count).ToString();
}
```